# chained select ajax call only works if value is a number

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

I have the following ajax snippet that chains 2 select boxes and is populated dynamically using values found in a mysql table.

This works great if the callType column is a numerical value like what is found in my data column SPG_CallType.  When I change this to use a column that contact alphabetical letters it breaks it.  I am assuming this is because the code works for just numerical values?  How do I update that part of the snippet to accept either alpha or numeric?

```
if (isset($_GET['key'])) {
    $key = $_GET['key'];
    switch ($key) {
        case 'callTypeSelect':
            $select = new SelectBox('Repair Type?','Choose a category');
            $res = mysql_query('SELECT DISTINCT SPG_CallType FROM ' . DB_TABLE . ' ORDER BY SPG_CallType ASC');
            $callTypes = array();
            for ($i = 0; list($callType) = mysql_fetch_row($res); $i++) {
                $callTypes[] = $callType;
                $select->addItem($callType, 'brandSelect-' . $callType);
            }
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            echo $select->toJSON();
            break;
        default:
            if (strpos($key, 'brandSelect-') === 0) {
                $callType = str_replace('brandSelect-', '', $key);
                $resBrands = mysql_query('SELECT SPG_Brand FROM ' . DB_TABLE
                    . ' WHERE SPG_CallType = ' . mysql_real_escape_string($callType) . ' ORDER BY SPG_Brand ASC');
                $select = new SelectBox('Choose a Manufacturer', 'Pick a brand');
                for ($i = 0; list($brand) = mysql_fetch_row($resBrands); $i++) {
                    $select->addItem($brand, 'result-' . $brand . '-' . $callType);
                }
                header('Content-type: application/json');
                echo $select->toJSON();
```

Comment: would this work? 
$select->addItem('\'' . $callType . '\'', 'brandSelect-' . $callType);

Comment: Yep, this is what I ended up doing or something similar.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@roryok answered the question, no way to give credits to comment though?

```
$select->addItem('\'' . $callType . '\'', 'brandSelect-' . $callType);
```